# cssで枠の中の画像をアスペクト比を保ちつつ拡大して全て表示する方法

Tags: css

divで囲まれたimg要素があります。

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="image" src="xxxx" />
</div>
```

- imgのアスペクト比を保ちつつdivの中いっぱいに拡大表示したいです。
- 画像はすべて表示されるようにしたいです。（divをはみ出さない)
- 縦か横に隙間が出来る場合は、画像は縦横センタリングしたいです。
- divの幅高さは固定です。

出来ればcssで実装していのですが、不可能であればjsを使うことも検討しています。
どのように実装すればいいでしょうか。

Comment: 関連?: [「縦横比が違う画像と同じ画像を縦横比をそろえて表示したいです。」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/30744/19110) -- スタック・オーバーフロー

Answer (score 3):

IE, safari 以外だとobject-fit, object-position というプロパティも使えるようです。

```
<style>
  .wrapper .image{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: center center;
  }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="xxxx" />
</div>
```

firefoxで確認したところ、綺麗にスケーリング・センタリングされてました。

Comment: そのものプロパティがCSS3であるのですね！  
しかしIE対応は捨てられないために採用できませんでした（対応ブラウザについて明記しておりませんでした…）

Comment: それは残念です。safariでもobject-fitまではサポートしているという情報がありました。 http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit  今後の参考になれば。